# Laravel Eloquent: Add elements to results of SQL query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to add elements to each result of a SQL query:

```
$res = DB::table('users')->get();
forEach ($res as $elem) {
    $elem['new_data'] = 'this is my new data';
}
```

But I get this error on the line in the loop:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

How should I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it says in English that You're trying to use `object of type stdClass` as an `array`. so just replace `$elem['new_data']` to `$elem->new_data`

Comment: I thought that only prototype oriented languages could do that. I can add properties dynamically to a class?

Comment: Actually it should. For example models which uses `setAttribute` method for that stuff. But for just stdClass I cannot predict, just give it a try.

Comment: Laravel has its own `setAttribute` function on its Model class. Well inherited from a trait, [HasAttribute](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L540).

IIRC, though, if you attempt to save that record with the new prop it'll throw a column not found error.

Comment: You are using **DB** and in question, you asked about **Eloquent**. If you use eloquent, you can create dynamic attributes and it will solve your problem like a charm. Try using Eloquent more instead of DB **(suggestion)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can use also laravel collection function
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

```
$res = DB::table('users')->get();

$res = $res->map(function($user) {
  $user->new_data = 'this is my data'
  return $user;
}

dd($res)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the error message.

**Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

$res is a collection of Objects

Use inside a foreach:

```
$elem->new_data
```

Insted of:

```
$elem['new_data']
```

$elem is not an array